How to provide ActivityCompat.requestPermissions with MainActivity in Android using Kotlin
I'm trying to integrate notifications with my app. Following google official documentation there's two ways to handle a notification. One is in the system tray to which the app will simply be launched by the system using launcher. The other is when the data of the notification needs to be processed by the app. I'm tackling the later.
I'm stuck at finding a way to provide MainActivity (class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()) as activity parameter to ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() as well as ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale().
Code is of the following:
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                MainActivity, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                MainActivity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                1000
            )
        }
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return
    }

where MainActivity gives an error:
Type mismatch.
Required: Activity
Found: MainActivity.Companion

I presume this is old clunk coming from previous installments regarding development on Android? Otherwise, I simply don't understand how you can have people rely on mechanisms like Context but then for workers have them rely on such "thing".
Anyone has any clue how to check & ask for permissions from a Worker?
For example, in the code labs I've implemented this worker that creates notifications, however, calling NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build()) will trigger an error telling the developer to implement the permission check.

Are you trying to request permission from a worker?

Yes @tyczj , from a worker

The only thing you should be doing in your worker is checking if you have permission to show a notification. Requesting a permission should be exclusively for Activities so that you can respond correctly to the user. A user would not want some random permission request showing up when an app is not even showing.

Thanks. Got confused by the code Android Studio generated when asked to add the permission check (see commented suggestions in the example code in the opening post).

shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale and requestPermissions required Activity as first parameter.
You should write this as
if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                1000
            )
}

Because when you pass only Activity name MainActivity it consider as Activity.Companion MainActivity.Companion

this doesn't work with a Worker type class

The answer is casting context as Activity:
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        val activity = context as Activity
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                activity, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                1000
            )
        } else {
            // deal with case when permission shouldn't be requested
        }
    }

NOTE: this assumes permissions have been handled PRIOR to hitting this case (when worker gets triggered to process data). E.g. handle permissions in MainActivity which subscribes to topic(s) and thus have permissions cleared out for data message processing (which prevents them from being processed if permissions are not granted by user when MainActivity is launched).

You should not be requesting from a worker, there is no guarantee that context is of type MainActivity and you also cannot respond to the user if they deny/grant. All you should be doing in the worker is check if it has been granted. All that other logic is for when the user is interacting with the app and has an activity to handle it. No user would want to have a random permission popup when an app they are not even using is in the background

Thanks! That makes sense. Can you post this as an answer to the question so I can mark it as such?
